# Random Forest evaluation for array with floats and integers - numpy

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, random-forest

I have an array which contains feature values as floats and I have an array of labels, which are integers - 1 and 0.

Example:
feature values:

```
[[  17.99    10.38   122.8   ...,    0.147    0.242    0.079]
 [  20.57    17.77   132.9   ...,    0.07     0.181    0.057]]
```

When I append labels to the array of feature values, the labels become floats.
Example - feature_values with appended 0:

```
[[  17.99    10.38   122.8   ...,    0.242    0.079    0.   ]]
```

When I run the following code:

```
training_set = data_features[:,0:9] 
test_set = data_features[:,9] 
seed = 7
num_trees = 100
max_features = 3
kfold = model_selection.KFold(n_splits=10, random_state=seed)
model = RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators=num_trees, max_features=max_features)
results = model_selection.cross_val_score(model, training_set, test_set, cv=kfold)
print(results.mean())
```

I get an error :

```
raise ValueError("Unknown label type: %r" % y_type)

ValueError: Unknown label type: 'continuous'
```

From what I've read, I see that this is happening because the labels are floats.

If I change the dtype of feature values to "int", the code does work, but I need to preserve the floats.

Is there any way to have labels as integers and feature values as floats so that the code works?

Comment: `test_set = data_features[:,9].astype(int)` this should do the trick.

Comment: but my test set is 10% from my training set, which is also floats. If I do .astype(int) it makes the test set zeros.

Comment: of you only need to convert one column to int. Got it. let me check. If it's a standard example can you share more code or link to it.

Comment: It was actually my mistake, i put the labels into a separate array and your solution works. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to convert the y_labels to integers so RandomForestClassifier can train on it.

```
test_set = data_features[:,9].astype(int)
```